# Criar select para filtar conteúdo de uma pagina web

Tags: wordpress

Estou criando um site no Wordpress e estou fazendo algumas modificações no tema que adquiri, estou usando o tema Agera e gostaria que no local daquela barrinha, onde ficam os botões para filtrar o conteúdo abaixo fosse um select, pois ao ver o site no celular aquela barra dependendo da quantidade de conteúdo fica grande e quebra em varias linhas com muitos botões e não fica legal.

o site para vocês verem o tema é este: http://agera.mpcthemes.net/

Se alguém quiser o tema para me ajudar é só me passar o email

O código é este e funciona legal

```
<div class="mpc-portfolio-categories">
<ul>
<li data-link="all"><a href="#all" class="active" title="All" data-link="all">All</a></li>
<li data-link="design"><a href="#design" title="Design" data-  link="design">Design</a></li>
<li data-link="photography"><a href="#photography" title="Photography" data-link="photography">Photography</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

mas se eu fizer isto ele não funciona

```
<select class="mpc-portfolio-categories">
<ul>
<option><li data-link="all"><a href="#all" class="active" title="All" data-link="all">All</a></li></option>
<option><li data-link="design"><a href="#design" title="Design" data-  link="design">Design</a></li></option>
<option><li data-link="photography"><a href="#photography" title="Photography" data-link="photography">Photography</a></li></option>
</ul>
</select>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta o código para os usuários poderem te ajudar.

Comment: Não basta só postar o código. Explique também quais alterações você está tentando fazer, caso contrário dificilmente alguém conseguirá te ajudar. Este site **não é** um fórum. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask].